# Table vs. ConstantArray efficiency with compilation

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I've been trying to optimize a bit of code the past couple of days, but think I might be misunderstanding how compilation on certain target functions works. As a most barebones example, I've attached a screenshot below of the speeds for array creation using ConstantArray, Table, and the compiled versions of each.

We see that ConstantArray is nearly 10x faster than Table in this most simple case (perhaps not surprisingly given that simplicity). When we try to compile, ConstantArray cannot be compiled, and so the time taken just increases because of overhead, I assume. However, the compiled Table call also increases in time. This is unexpected to me, so I figure I must be doing something wrong in this comparison. Any thoughts on how to yield a speed increase from compiling Table, if it is possible in such a situation? I should also note that using Array is categorically slower than both other options, for both uncompiled, and compiled.

[image]

Comment: Not quite related to the discussion but it's just funny: `Compile[{}, Table[1., 10000000]]` is fully compiled, but `Compile[{}, Table[1., 10^7]]` isn't. One has to use the old syntax `Compile[{}, Table[1., {10^7}]]`. Tested in 12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 4, 2020) (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: Great question (+1). Also in version 12 for macos, even `Compile[{}, Table[1., {10000000}],
 CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]` takes four times longer than `ConstantArray[1., {10000000}]`. Hard to say what goes wrong there.

Comment: There are a few functions like this. With the old compiler I found that functions like NestWhileList and Erf (to 10 thousand digits precision) were slower with the compiler. A very senior programmer at WRI explained to me that this was because the symbolic nature of NestWhileList and the symbolic processing done internally for Erf are so efficient that it beats compilation. Haven't tried it on the new compiler yet, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few additional options that improve performance with the functions in the [Code Compilation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CodeCompilation.html) guide, In version 12.1 these are experimental functions so they may change in future versions.

I'll give timings of `c1` and `c2` on my ancient laptop for reference.

```
c1 = Compile[{}, ConstantArray[1., 10000000]];
c2 = Compile[{}, Table[1., 10000000]];
a3 = c1[]; // RepeatedTiming
a4 = c2[]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.344, Null}
> {0.584, Null}
> ```

With [`FunctionCompile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompile.html) and a [`Typed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Typed.html) argument we get a boost to both functions.

```
c3 = FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[n, "Integer64"], ConstantArray[1., n]]];
c4 = FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[n, "Integer64"], Table[1., n]]];
a5 = c3[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming
a6 = c4[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.24, Null}
> {0.240, Null}
> ```

We can boost performance even more with [`KernelFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KernelFunction.html) on the Wolfram Language functions and [`TypeSpecifier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TypeSpecifier.html) on their result.  However, there is a regression with `Table` which may explain why these compile functions are still experimental.

```
c5 = FunctionCompile[
  Function[
   Typed[n, "Integer64"],
   Typed[
     KernelFunction[ConstantArray], {"Real64", "Integer64"} -> 
      TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]
     ][1., n]
   ]];

c6 = FunctionCompile[
  Function[
   Typed[n, "Integer64"],
   Typed[
     KernelFunction[Table], {"Real64", "Integer64"} -> 
      TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]
     ][1., n]
   ]];

a7 = c5[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming
a8 = c6[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.10, Null}
> {0.75, Null}
> ```

So although these experimental functions still need some work in some cases they are giving a glimpse of the improvements that can be expected over [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) once they are finalised.  In this example `ConstantArray` dropped from 0.344 with `Compile` down to 0.10 with the `FunctionCompile` - `KernelFunction` combo.  While `Table` dropped from 0.584 with `Compile` to 0.24 with `FunctionCompile`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a bit disheartening that to achieve even modest boosts so much cumbersome code is required...

Comment: @KHAAAAAAAAN I think it is because Wolfram Language is dynamically typed so to get around all of the options a function can take you need to specify exactly the option you are targeting to make the compiled code faster.